Use of a Service in Spring Boot EnvironmentPostProcessor
I have a class that implements the EnvironmentPostProcessor to define some properties from an ini file. I also have a deferred log to write logs in the postprocess. I also want to write a custom dump file, if some errors occur during the postprocessor. I have a dump service to do this. But the dump service is not instantiated at the time of the postprocessor, because it is to early in the lifecycle. I think therefore it's better to avoid relying on Spring dependency injection for that service.
public class IniFileEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private final Log log;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final DumpService dumpService;

    public IniFileEnvironmentPostProcessor(DeferredLogFactory logFactory, DumpService dumpService) {
        log = logFactory.getLog(IniFileEnvironmentPostProcessor.class);
        this.dumpService = dumpService;
    }


    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {...}
}

The use of Direct Instantiation is working but this does not create a spring bean but a simple java object:
public IniFileEnvironmentPostProcessor(DeferredLogFactory logFactory) {
    log = logFactory.getLog(IniFileEnvironmentPostProcessor.class);
    this.dumpService = new DumpService();
}

I don't think this is a good solution. How could this be done properly, to have a dump service in the post processor?

You don't. The EnvironmentPostProcessor operates very early in the startup process before even when there are beans. Now if you start trying to obtain beans from the context that is starting, you will get a race condition and if not you will trigger very (and thus too) early bean initialization.

If you want to load an ini file you might want to look at Apache Configuration which has support for that as well as Spring (Boot) integration. You can use your EnvironmentPostProcessor to configure the specific PropertySource.

If this works, then it's okay that DumpService is not a Spring bean. If you want to do it right, start by separating DumpService into an interface and an implementation. If you want a more advanced solution, consider the SPI mechanism. It will help you avoid direct instantiation.
Create a text file in the META-INF/services/ folder with the name of your service interface, containing the name of your service implementation.
For example, a file
META-INF/services/com.example.DumpService

with the content
com.example.DumpServiceImpl

Then use the following code to create an instance of your service:
ServiceLoader<DumpService> services = ServiceLoader.load(DumpService.class);
for (DumpService service : services) {
   // choose the required implementation
}

Using this approach, you can easily replace one implementation of your service with another in the future.
